# Create a diagram with frequency

Tags: tikz-arrows, size

I would want to draw this diagram with the number of frequency which is represented by the thickness of the line. The size of the text box should be based on the number of letters of the label itself.
Thanks so much.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.